# Any ideas for this Conditional Probability Problem?

Tags: probability, logic

I spent a lot of time in calculating this problem but it didn't work, any ideas?

In a school that have $25000$ students, every year $1.5\%$ of student number enter admission exam and $2$ students pass.

Let $Y$ be the probability that a student who entered the exam in a year $X$ and didn't pass, then entered the exam in the year $X+1$, and pass.

Let $Z$ be the probability that a student who didn't enter the exam in year $X$, then entered the exam in the year $X+1$ and pass.

Knowing that $Y=544*Z$, what would be the number of students who didn't enter the exam in a year $X$ and passed the exam in the year $X+1$?

Comment: In view of the small number of newly admitted students each year this school must have some very old students on its roll.